# Parametrized NgRx selector fires unnecessarily

Tags: angular, ngrx, state-management

I'm using a parametrized selector to select an array property of a state: (`state.user.lists['listName']`).

However, the selector also fires whenever another list entry (`state.user.lists['otherListName']`) or another user property (`state.user.name`) has been changed.

```
const getSpecificList = (listIdentifier: listIdentifiers) => {
  return createSelector(
    getCurrentUser,
    (user: User) => {
      return user.lists[listIdentifier] ? user.lists[listIdentifier]  : undefined;
    }
  );
};
```

Looking forward to your ideas on this.

#### Edit:

As I've received a close vote for 'unclear what I'm asking':
What could be the reason for this unexpected behavior? I would expect the selector to only ever fire whenever the respective list has been changed.

Comment: can you share the usage?

Comment: As per your comments what I understand is, you deriving a selector from 'getCurrentUser'. If you modify any property for the user object selector will run it recalculate the new state. ***it is expected behaviour.

Comment: I guess you might be creating new object instances in some of your reducers. Like `{ ...state.user.lists}`